# Householder reflector which reflects a given vector through given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to construct Householder reflector which reflects any vector $x \in \mathbb {R}^{n}$ through $r$ dimensional subspace $W$ of $\mathbb {R}^{n}$. Also, I want to calculate computational complexity.

**My approach:** Let $u$ be the unit vector normal to $W$. Then reflection of $x$ across $W$ is the vector that lies on the other side of $W$ from $x$, exactly the same distance from $W$ as is $x$, and having the same projection into $W$ as $x$. Difference between $x$ and its reflection is exactly twice the projection of $x$ along the unit normal $u$ to $W$. This observations give $reflector (x) = (I - 2uu^{t})x$, where the matrix $I - 2uu^{t}$ is called the Householder matrix. $t$ denotes the transpose.

Please suggest me whether I am correct or not. Also, could any body help me how to compute computational complexity in this construction?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: *the* unit vector? But if $r<n-1$, there are ininitely many such vectors. And in the usual case where $r=n-1$ and $W$ is an hyperplane, there are two, $u$ and $-u$. Also, what are you really trying to compute here? You have just written a reflection matrix. Do you want to compute a QR decomposition?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I got this question from one of assignment. Could you please specify under what circumstances my approach could be correct? What should be correct problem? Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I fully agree with @Jean-Claude Arbaut, and especially with the fact that speaking about (Householder) reflection makes sense only wrt hyperplanes ($r=n-1$).

Regarding the complexity of **applying** a Householder reflection to a vector, it is $O(n)$, because

$$(I-2uu^t)v=v-2u(u^tv)=v+(-2u^tv)v$$

that can be decomposed into 4 successive operations,

- dot product $a=u^tv  \ \ \ (O(n))$.
- number product $b=-2 \times a  \ \ \ \ (O(1))$.
- product $w=bv$ of a number and a vector $ \ \ \ (O(n))$.
- addition $v+w$ of two vectors $ \ \ \ (O(n))$.

which makes an $O(n)$ operation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I understood how to compute complexity.